# Why we need parameterized Constructor

Tags: java

What is the need of parameterized constructor, while we can use default constructor object to pass the value

Comment: I'm a bit confused -> How do you pass a value to a default constructor o.0

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, could you please provide an example in form of code?

Comment: Student s=new student() ;

Comment: You do not _need_ any parameterized constructors, but they can make your life easier. You don't need any high-level programming languages either, you can do everything in assembler...

Comment: @Subashini if you have a `Student` with a name, with a parameterized constructor you can easily set that name once you create the object `new Student("John")`, whereas with your approach you'd have to set it later: `Student s = new Student(); s.setName("John");`

Comment: Student s=new student() ;                                   s. a=10; // we can pass the value like this na, then why we need parameterized Constructor

Comment: @Subashini I sincerely advise you to read some good Java articles or books to understand the basic concepts before starting Java programming. You can set the value using dot notation. But there are cases where created object should have initial values or you want to do some validation/processing on values before object creation,  parameterized constructor comes very handy in such cases. There are many other applications which can't be listed here. Also, you should not allow accessing your instance variables using dot notation outside your class (e.g. s.a=10); it is one of the OOPs principle.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you have got the following class:

```
class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

How are you going to set the values of `id` and `name` after creating the object of this class?

You might say that you can write `getters` and `setters` for these and set the value. However, this would result in the following:

- You need to explicitly write the code to set these values after creating each object
- Your Employee objects will be mutable

What if you want to make these objects immutable and at the same time, want to write some readable code as well? That's when you will use a parametrised constructor.

This is just one use case though, you can read more about it [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-need-constructors-in-Java).

Answer (score 3):

Parameterized Constructor is useful when you want to initialise the variables while creating object.